# Open modal from tab bar

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I have 3 tabs and I want to open a modal when the user presses on the second tab at the moment it just navigates to the screen.

```js
      Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
tabs: [
  { screen: 'Settings', title: 'Settings' },
  { screen: 'CreateRecord', title: 'Record' },
  { screen: 'Main', title: 'Main' }
],
animationType: 'fade'});
```

Thanks in advance